# User authentication in mobile app

Tags: android, ios, api, rest, appcelerator

How do all these mobile apps login users? I did a lot of research and read tutorials but I can't find a definitive answer...

I created an API for my Codeigniter web app using Phil Sturgeon's [REST server](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver). Now I need to create a mobile app (for Android and ios) that works with remote data from my web server. (I decided to build my app with [Appcelerator](http://www.appcelerator.com/).)

My goal is to allow users to log in from my mobile app and make CRUD operations via the REST server API. The API uses [HTTP digest access authentication](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver#authentication) but I'm concerned about security because it sends a username and password over HTTP. Is there a more secure way to authenticated users?

After a user is logged in how will they perform CRUD operations without logging in again?

Comment: Are you looking for some kind of security that's not achieved just by switching to HTTPS?

Comment: Is switching to HTTPS sufficient? I'm also considering using API keys.

Comment: I think what a lot of apps do is exchange a username/password for a token that represents that the user logged in at a certain time over SSL, then use that for a period of time before they force reauthentication

Comment: digest sends an md5 of the authentication elements. the password is not sent as is.

Comment: @JeffS for example, letting users log in directly on the website from the mobile app and saving a cookie with a token? Then I can use that token to perform CRUD from the mobiel app. The token is sent via HTTPS

Comment: @CyberJunkie Cookies and REST do not go together very well. Authentication seems to be a common use for cookies in REST, but I still would not pick it unless it's unavoidable.

Comment: @CyberJunkie I had meant doing the auth and returning a token, which should then be in every request as a `Authentication: Bearer` header. Many HTTP clients used with REST do not handle cookies well

Comment: @JeffS thanks! Tokens sounds like the best solution.

Comment: @JefferyThomas in that case I'll just return the token with a JSON response and maybe store it in the device db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Security is a matter of trade-offs. You need to answer several question.

1. How much pain can I put the user through to protect the content?
2. How valuable is the protected content?
3. What are the consequences of breached security?

Unless you are storing banking information, confidential/personal information, or the content can be irrevocably altered/deleted, HTTPS with digest authentication are fine.

NOTE: digest does not transmit passwords.